# No ping localhost after starting RAS service with demand-dial PPPoE connection

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, localhost

I have a big problem on my Windows Server 2008 Enterprise x64 SP2 non-R2:

There is no ping to `127.0.0.1`: Request timeout. Ping to `::1` (localhost on IPv6) is still alive.

I mean, server has no interface 127.0.0.1 at all! So ping absence is just a 
tip of an iceberg..

I found that problem appears after starting `Routing and Remote Access` service (RRAS). I have next configuration there:

- 1 NIC called `LAN` (10.0.0.0)
- 1 NIC called `WAN` (192.168.112.0)
- and a persistent PPPoE connection to internet over it called `Inet`

And one static route making `Inet` to be default route: `0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 metric 1`

After starting server, 127.0.0.1 can be pinged. After starting RAS server - not.

Has anybody the same problem? How can it be fixed? I was asking the same question on [TechNet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverPN/thread/cdb5b87a-6f29-45c9-8ddb-de4001789d3f/#5e447fb8-9dd3-499f-b9b5-6c0d4588088c) but got no answer.

Here is `route print -4` output: http://pastebin.com/d767d7c5a

Comment: Can you post the full output of **route print**? Is it possible to ping the server from another system? What are the firewall settings like?

Comment: Granted that you should be able to ping 127.0.0.1, but why is it such a big problem? 127.0.0.1 is a loopback address and shouldn't affect networking on the server otherwise.

Comment: I need localhost because many server applications binds themselves to 127.0.0.1:port, e.g. MySQL, Tomcat in VMware Server, etc

Comment: Thanks for interesting in my question. I have edited my post. Only default Windows Firewall. Turning it off doesn't helped. Pinging all other interfaces (::1, 10.0.0.1, 192.168.112.45, 81.200.116.70) goes fine! o_O

Comment: joeqwerty, the number of things that rely on the loopback interface is massive, MySQL and Tomcat are just two of them.

Comment: The routing table looks sane to me. 

Check if you can reach 127.1.2.3 (or anything else in 127.0.0.0/8)

What does your NAT configuration look like?

Comment: No ping (Request timed out) to any host from 127.255.255.255. NAT for IPv4 in RRAS has following records: LAN (private), WAN (public, NAT enabled), Inet (public, NAT enabled). No data for pools and ports. I think this is a bug of Next Generation TCP/IP Stack in Windows 2008..(( and nothing could help me. Even SP2 didn't help.

Comment: At this point I would suggest opening a support ticket at Microsoft... And post the outcome here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
netsh int ip reset
```

has fixed the issue!

Answer (score -1):

The interface `127.0.0.1` can come from your `hosts` file. It's well worth checking to see if it exists. I don't quite know how RRAS would change this, but it still deserves checking.

Open up the file `%SYSTEMDRIVE%\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` in notepad and see if there is a line:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

If there isn't add it. It might fix all your problems. It's not ideal, but it should be a sufficient bandaid.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answer. I think it's better to say that name localhost comes from the hosts file. Without it only IP addresses exists. But I can be wrong. Hosts file on the server contains both records. I have already checked it.

Comment: Sorry, you're right about the wording. The 'name', not the interface. My mistake!